# Include a custom python module in multiple modules separately

Tags: python, aws-lambda, python-module

I have made a custom python module (say `awesome-lib.py`), which is to be imported and used by the multiple other python modules(`module1.py`, `module2.py` etc). The problem is that all the modules need to be in separate folders and each of them should have a copy of `awesome-lib.py` for them to import it. I thought of two options for doing this:

1. Each module folder will have a copy of `awesome-lib.py` in it. That way I can `import awesome-lib` and used it in each module. But issue is when I have to make any changes in `awesome-lib.py`. I would have to copy the file in each module folder separately, so this might not be a good approach.
2. I can package the `awesome-lib.py` using `distutils`. Whenever I make the change in the module, I will update `awesome-lib.py` in each module using some script. But still **I want the awesome-lib distribution package to be individually included in each module folder.**

Can anyone please tell me an efficient way to achieve this? So that I can easily change one file and the changes are reflected in all the modules separately.

*P.S: I want the `awesome-lib.py` in each module folder separately because I need to zip the contents of it and upload each module on AWS Lambda as a Lambda zip package.*

Comment: If it feels like you're doing it wrong, you probably are doing it wrong.

Comment: Yes, so any work around for it? :)

Comment: I don't know much about AWS specifically but I would question the design of a system that _makes_ you put a copy of your module in every folder individually. That's the thing it seems like you're doing wrong. There should be some way to install `awesome-lib.py` centrally and have each module use it, or to express the dependency of `module1.py` etc. on `awesome-lib.py` and have a dependency resolution system take care of it.

Comment: In case of any other external library, I install it using `pip install <some-lib> -t /install/to/path` and then package that as a zip and upload zip on AWS Lambda. But now when `awesome-lib.py` is dependent on multiple modules and it is possible that it would change then what to do

Answer (score 0):

let only one copy of awesome-lib.py placed where it is placed and append it's path in other modules. let sample path is "/home/user/awesome-lib.py"

Add following code in every other module you want to import awesome-lib.py

`import sys
sys.path.append('home/user/awesome-lib')
import awesome-lib`

*Note: path of awesome-lib may differ on your choice*

Comment: This technically works, but it's a bad idea except for single-use scripts because once you move any of the files involved to another computer, or change the directory structure, everything breaks.

Comment: why to change directory structure?? just let your modules where you want them and then simply append it's path.. example above only shows how to do it.

Comment: The issue is when the module is packaged as zip, it needs to have an individual library in the zip package. If it doesn't, and I upload it on AWS Lambda, then that path won't be recognized on AWS Lambda